# Spring AOP pointcut and advice in separate module

Tags: spring-aop

In my web application I have three modules, A B and C. B depends on A and C depends on B. Now, I want an aspect to define the behavior of methods in module B.

If I do not want to define the aspect in same module B, then should I define the Aspect in module A or C? Or it does not matter at all?

I am wondering if aspect weaving in spring is affected by build dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which kind of aspect weaving you are asking. The kind of weaving that Spring does is done while the container is built. So you can perfectly weave new aspects to already compiled and packaged classes at a latter time. With the context you introduced, I usually declare aspects in the C module, which is my application, and leave the libraries A and B alone.

Comment: Thanks! I am doing the same thing. But, the aspect is not called for any method in module B but it is called for methods in C. Intellij shows that pointcut expressions are correct and it is applied to required methods in B. Any idea on what may be causing this?

Comment: Are the objects of module B upon which you call methods Spring beans, defined as `<bean />` elements or stereotypes of some sort brought to the container with a `<component-scan />`?

Comment: Yes those are spring beans annotated by @Service. Those beans are instantiated properly and working normally otherwise.

Comment: So, just to be sure, those beans are retrieved using the Spring context, with `getBean()` or injected to other beans. No `new` operator involved. Does the defined pointcuts satisfy the method calls (return type, package, pattern for the class / interface, parameters)? Apart from those simple checks. Are the B objects already bytecode enhanced in some way?

Comment: I have defined a simple pointcut expression for just public methods which is working only for methods in module C. Module B is no different other than its methods are advised by another aspect in another module D. Does it make any difference?

Comment: No it doesn't. If the beans are described and retrieved by Spring, the classes can be anywhere in the classpath, Spring doesn't care. For the sake of narrowing things down, do the pointcuts refer to the concrete class or an interface of the class? Do B objects have an interface or are they CGLIB enhanced? I've read about a notion of exact pattern, it might be related.